# Albanian minimal pairs for r vs. rr, xh vs. gj, and q vs. ç

Tags: albanian

can anyone provide some minimal pairs for these in Albanian?

I have just begun studying the language and would like to improve my ability to hear the differences in these, which is challenging as a native English speaker.

I've found a ton of examples on here of l vs. ll, but not for the below:

- r vs. rr
- xh vs. gj
- q vs. ç

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

- *arë* "soil" vs *arrë* "nut"
- *çaj* "cut" vs *qaj* "cry"
- *xham* "glass" vs *gjak* "blood" (near-minimal).

More details:

In the International Phonetic Alphabet, here's how these contrasts would be written:

> /ɾ/ vs /r/
>   /d͡ʒ/ vs /ɟ/
>   /t͡ʃ/ vs /c/

The first of these is the easiest to explain: *r* is a tap, while *rr* is a trill. In other words, in *r* your tongue flaps once, like a very short "d", and in *rr* it flaps several times. Spanish makes this same distinction, written the same way, and recordings should be easy to find: the classic minimal pair is *pero* "but" / *perro* "dog".

The second and third contrasts are more difficult. In Gheg Albanian the distinction is entirely lost, and this is spreading to some speakers of Tosk Albanian.

The sounds written *ç* and *xh* are "affricates", like in the English words ***ch***urch and ***j***ar. They're pronounced by stopping the flow of air, then releasing the obstruction partially. The sounds written *q* and *gj* on the other hand are "plosives", closer to the sounds in English ***k***een and ***g***ear, pronounced by blocking the flow of air and then releasing it all at once.

English doesn't have Albanian's *q* and *gj* as distinct sounds, but they're very close to the pronunciation of English *k* and *g* before the vowel in "feed". These sounds also exist in Hungarian, where they're written *ty* and *gy* (as in "Magyar").